# Date conversion in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a Timestamp field in my collection. The format in which it is storing is "**2016-02-06 20:24:39 -0500**".

I need to convert in ISODate in **mongodb** CLI. Can any one suggest me how to convert the date in ISODate format.

Comment: Is it a date object or just a string?

Comment: Its a string. I need it in the format of 2017-02-06T15:42:00.684Z.

Comment: You could make a mongo native javascript witch loops through the collection, reads every  row and for the the date string converts to date object and updates accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do something with a MongoDB function in a loop. For example, I have the following document;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b036ff8f79f3a0ab96a1cd"),
    "date" : "2016-02-06 20:24:39 -0500"
}
```

I can convert the string value of `date` to an ISO format with this query

```
db.getCollection('test').find({_id:ObjectId("58b036ff8f79f3a0ab96a1cd")}).forEach( function(doc) {
    var objDate = ISODate(doc.date); //Make an ISO date
    doc.date = objDate; //Overwrite the value
    db.test.save(doc); //Save the document
});
```

Now, the document will look like this;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b036ff8f79f3a0ab96a1cd"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-02-06T20:24:39.000Z")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help :)